# Convert multiple if else to switch case in C/ C++

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, switch-statement

In C/C++ I have scenario where if should be executed on the basis of empty size.
If size of variable a is 0 then string 'add name' should be printed otherwise 'leave it' string should be printed. But I have switch cases for encoding as well for each case there will be different if condition.

```
 switch(encoding)
    case utf:
        if(a->size-5 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"add name";
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"leave it";
        }
    case ansi:
        if(a->size-4 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"add name";
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"leave it";
        }
    case ansi8:
        if(a->size-8 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"add name";
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"leave it";
        }
```

I want to do it in minimal way. So what is the best way to do that.

Comment: Please pick one language, the one you are actually using. C and C++ are different languages with different solutions to the same problems. The term "C/C++" only makes sense for language agnostic tools or IDEs but as soon as it comes to code details do matter

Comment: Ternary operator could replace the if-else blocks, leading to 'minimal' code.

Comment: You could do something like `switch(encoding) case utf: offset = 5; break; case ansi: offset = 4; break; ...` and then do a single `if(a->size - offset == 0)` branch at the end, instead of repeating the if-else in each case statement.

Comment: You should parse one protocol layer per module. Here, you're having this big set of code handle the higher level "which encoding" layer, AND the lower "is it the right size" layer. If the encoding is X, pass the data to the X decoder. Let the X decoder worry about if the data is valid X-type.

Comment: `a->size - 4 == 0` is a very bad idea compared to `a->size == 4`. You're introducing unnecessary arithmetic, with the risk of overflow.  What if the type is `int`, and `a->size` has the value `INT_MIN`? The behavior is undefined, and could have been avoided by just leaving the `4` on the opposite side of the `==` sign.

Answer (score 6):

I don't fully understand what solution you are expecting, but - same as suggested in a comment - when removing duplication from your code we are left with:

```
    if(a->size-offset == 0)
    {
        cout<<"add name";
    }
    else
    {
       cout<<"leave it";
    }
```

Where `offset` can be determined via:

```
int offset = 0;
switch(encoding) {
   case utf: offset = 5; break;
   case ansi: offset = 4; break;
   case asni8: offset = 8; break;
}
```

Probably a cleaner solution would be to use a polymorphic type such that differences in the encoding are encapsulated in virtual methods, and you can write:

```
    if(a->check_size())
    {
        cout<<"add name";
    }
    else
    {
       cout<<"leave it";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that ternary operator is the best approach.

```
 switch(encoding) {
    case utf:
        (a->size - 5 == 0) ? std::cout << "add name" : std::cout << "leave it";
        break;
    case ansi:
        (a->size - 4 == 0) ? std::cout << "add name" : std::cout << "leave it";
        break;
    case ansi8:
        (a->size - 8 == 0) ? std::cout << "add name" : std::cout << "leave it";
        break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write your code like this:

```
//...
//assuming utf, ansi, and ansi8 are enumerated constants
static const int encoding2size[]={ [utf]=5,[ansi]=4,[ansi8]=8 };
//...
if(a->size - encoding2size[encoding] == 0) cout<<"add name";
else cout<<"leave it";
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a separate function for the if-else part that takes in an offset as input, and call the function with the desired input (desired offset) from each case in the switch case statement? This will at least help avoiding code duplication.